# How to add Refresh trigger to a class which is annotated with @ApplicationScope

Tags: java, spring-boot, singleton, postconstruct, application-scope

Right now I have an `InitialReferenceLoaderImpl` which is annotated by `@ApplicationScope` and the function is annotated by `@PostConstruct`, in this class I'm loading my `Application Properties` from the SQL table, but the problem is, If users change something on `Application Properties` table, it does not get reflected directly, User needs to restart the server, which I don't want.

I want the user to hit the `/refresh` URL so that `Application Properties` can be reloaded.

Sorry for the confusing explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem by using `Bean.refresh()`, The solution I was seeking, was I wanted a `/refresh` end-point which will refresh my bean to do that I followed the following steps -

1. I Autowired the `ConfigurableApplicationContext` 
   `@Autowired`
   `private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;`
2. In the endpoint I initialized the bean -
   `ReferenceClass bean = context.getBean(ReferenceClass.class);`
3. Refreshed is using `.refresh()`
   `bean.refresh();`

That's it, it solved my issue, once the user hits the `/refresh`  endpoint it refreshes my bean.